# Is there a way to make JavaScript read strings as strings when multipying by numbers?

Tags: javascript, string, numbers, integer

I am (using JavaScript) trying to get an output of 50 dashes as a banner like this:

"--------------------------------------------------"

I have so far tried the following:

```js
let a = []
for (var i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
  a.push("-")
}

console.log(...a)
```

and

```js
console.log("-" * 50)
```

These do not work, as in the first one, there are spaces in between the dashes.
The second one returns `NaN`, which is not what I need either.

The regular way I used to do this in Python was:

```
print("-" * 50)
```

This gave the perfect result of "----------------------------------------------------".

The `print()` function being Python's equivalent of `console.log()`.

However, this does not work in JavaScript, as said before.

I also figured out that this does not work due to the fact that the string is parsed as a number.

Is there a way to achieve the "----------------------------------------------------" banner in JavaScript without typing it manually, or is there a way to make sure that "-" is not parsed as a number?

Comment: Although an answer was already given, just for the record, on your first example you can do `console.log(a.join(""));` and it would work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, javascript lack of that feature. But you could use `repeat()` on ECMAScript6:

```js
console.log("-".repeat(50))
```

This is Mozilla's reference https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/repeat

Answer (score 0):

```js
let a = []
for (var i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
  a.push("-")
}

a=a.toString();

a=a.replace(/,/g,'');
console.log(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use an Array:

```js
let a = Array(50).fill('-').join('')

console.log(a)
```